# Error in struct and 2d arrays in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct Room {
    int values[4][4];
    int size;
} Room;

int createRoom(Room *pm, char *mazefilename)
{

    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;
    pm = (Room *)malloc(sizeof(Room *));
    input = fopen(mazefilename, "r");

    int a = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int count;

    char  line[6];


    fscanf(input, "%s", line);
    while (!feof(input)) {
        printf("Line is  %s\n", line);
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int c = line[i] - '0';

            pm->values[a][i] = c;
        }
        a++;
        fscanf(input, "%s", line);
    }
    fclose(input);
    return a;
}
```

This is giving me segmentation fault-

```
Line is  1001
Line is  1001
Line is  1101
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is it giving me segmentation fault.If I just print the lines instead of `pm->values[a][i]=c;`,it gives me the correct output.So I think something is wrong with this line-`pm->values[a][i]=c;`

My input file is-

```
1001
1001
1101
1109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating enough space

```
pm=(Room *)malloc(sizeof(Room *));
```

allocates one pointer, you need

```
pm = malloc(sizeof(Room));
```

Other issues with your code

1. [Don't cast `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495).
2. [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1983495).
3. You don't check the return value either of `malloc()` or `fopen()`, you must check that if you want your code to be robust.
4. The allocated pointer, will not be valid outside of the function, you have three options

   1. Return the pointer and pass `a` as a pointer, so you can update the counter inside the function.
   2. Pass `pm` as a pointer to pointer, i.e. `Room **pm` and pass it's address, you must then use the dereference operator to modify `pm` something like

      ```
      *pm = malloc(sizeof(Room));
      ```
   3. This

      ```
      Room * createRoom(char *mazefilename)
      {

         Room * pm;
         FILE * input;
         FILE * output;

         pm = malloc(sizeof(Room));
         if (pm == NULL)
           return NULL;

         input = fopen(mazefilename,"r");
         if (input == NULL)
         {
           free(pm);
           return NULL;
         }

         int i = 0, j = 0;
         int count;

         char  line[6];

         pm->size = 0;
         while (fscanf(input,"%s",line) == 1)
         {
             printf("Line is  %s\n", line);
             for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
             {
               int c = line[i] - '0';
               pm->values[a][i] = c;
             }
             pm->size++;
          }
          fclose(input);
          return pm;
      }
      ```

   this third option, seems to be the way you intended to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.Can you tell me why is `while (!feof(file))` wrong,it seems to be working in my case?

Comment: Just changing this `pm = malloc(sizeof(Room));` worked for me . Also if suppose I wanted to use dynamic array in my struct say `int ** values`,then how can I allocate memory for such double pointers?

Comment: Please read the link about `while (!feof(file))` and check how I fixed it in the , and yes the main problem is you was allocating space for a pointer, instead of doing it for a `struct`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function signature and malloc call are incorrect for what you are trying to do. If you want to allocate space for the passed in `pm` pointer you need to pass that pointer's address:

```
int createRoom(Room ** pm,char *mazefilename)
```

And then your `malloc()` call has to allocate enough space for a `Room` structure, not a Room pointer:

```
*pm=malloc(sizeof(Room));
```